# Nokogiri CSS method to 2D array

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm attempting to create a simple web scraper, but I'm having some trouble.

The structure of the website is like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-01-18">Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/210190">TIGERS</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-01-25">Sun 01-25-15 06:40 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208345">LIONS</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-02-01">Sun 02-01-15 12:50 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/210041">CLAY</a></td>
</tr>
```

What I currently have is this:

```
games = page.css("td[class='gametime']").map{|game| game.parent.css("a").text}
```

This returns an array of strings with three elements (in this example). But what I am attempting to get is a 2D array, where, for example:

```
games[0][0] #=> Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PM
games[0][1] #=> CYCLONES
games[0][2] #=> TIGERS
```

I do not want this (what I currently am getting):

```
games[0] #=> Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PMCYCLONESTIGERS
```

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
games = page.css("td.gametime").map { |i| i.parent.css("a").map { |j| j.text } }
```

For each `td.gametime`, go to its parent and grab all `a` tags then map them to their text. This will give you an array of three values for each game, and an array of arrays for the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `text` is going to make an array for you. I think you'll need to nest `map` statements:

```
games = page.css("td[class='gametime']").map{|game| game.parent.css("a").map(&:text)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-01-18">Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/210190">TIGERS</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-01-25">Sun 01-25-15 06:40 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208345">LIONS</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-02-01">Sun 02-01-15 12:50 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/210041">CLAY</a></td>
</tr>
EOT
```

Here's the code:

```
games = doc.search('tr').map{ |tr| tr.search('td').map(&:text) }
# => [["Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PM", "CYCLONES", "TIGERS"],
#     ["Sun 01-25-15 06:40 PM", "LIONS", "CYCLONES"],
#     ["Sun 02-01-15 12:50 PM", "CYCLONES", "CLAY"]]
games[0][0] # => "Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PM"
games[0][1] # => "CYCLONES"
games[0][2] # => "TIGERS"
```

It isn't necessary to grab the inner tags inside the `<td>` tags for this HTML. Sometimes there's additional text to be ignored, which would make it necessary, but since it's simple, the code can be simple. `text` for the `<td>` nodes will return the text nodes embedded inside them.

I seriously doubt the HTML they're serving is that plain, and without a bit more detail I can't give a more accurate answer. (It behooves/benefits you to provide adequately detailed and accurate input.) The general idea though, is to find the table containing the rows you want, then drill down:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<table class="foo">
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-01-18">Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/210190">TIGERS</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-01-25">Sun 01-25-15 06:40 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208345">LIONS</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="gametime"><a href="/facilities/22/games?exact_date=15-02-01">Sun 02-01-15 12:50 PM</a></td>
    <td class="gamehome"><a href="/facilities/22/teams/208362">CYCLONES</a></td>
    <td><a href="/facilities/22/teams/210041">CLAY</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="bar">
</table>
EOT
```

And the modified code:

```
games = doc.search('table.foo tr').map{ |tr| tr.search('td').map(&:text) }
# => [["Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PM", "CYCLONES", "TIGERS"],
#     ["Sun 01-25-15 06:40 PM", "LIONS", "CYCLONES"],
#     ["Sun 02-01-15 12:50 PM", "CYCLONES", "CLAY"]]
games[0][0] # => "Sun 01-18-15 09:10 PM"
games[0][1] # => "CYCLONES"
games[0][2] # => "TIGERS"
```